# How to maintain full width image aspect ratio until specific height, but then crop height?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I want my images to maintain their full width and aspect ratio until they reach 600px height, at which point they crop the height (and still maintain full width). This is where it gets tricky for me because I want to avoid using `background-image` to accomplish my goal.

Most of my images are `1920x1080` aspect ratio, so once the screen gets smaller than `1070px`, the default aspect ratio should be fine. The image auto-scales to `1070x600` for `1070px` screens, or `800x450` for `800px` screens, or `400x225` for `400px` screens, and so on. All good.

But once the screen is bigger than `1070px`, the default aspect ratio no longer works for me because height creeps past 600px. I'd like the images to auto-crop to a `600px` height at this point, keeping the full width intact:

- **For 1920px screens:** crop the image to 1920x600
- **For 1500px screens:** crop the image to 1500x600

And so on.

`add_image_size( 'jd-custom-size', 1920, 600, true );` isn't enough because at a small screen, i.e. 800px, it crops the image to 800x250.

`add_image_size( 'jd-custom-size', 9999, 600, true );` creates the same problem.

I'm sure I'm not the first person with this goal, but I'm not quite sure how to google it. Most search queries just turn up basic `add_image_size` questions.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you can change the image dinamically by detecting first the screen size

Comment: max-height + object-fit, or just max-height if a container wraps them ... any code/snippets to share and show your actual issue ? :) for the html/css part  else you also have http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecrop.php combined with srcset in html could also be usefull to load an alternative image

Comment: G-Cyr, this is exactly what I needed. The other responses on this thread could work, but only at specific breakpoints. This one crops 1px at a time until it reaches a 1070px screen, at which point I can turn off the height restriction. If you want to post a formal answer, I'll mark it as correct.

I basically set a div around the image, added `width: 100%; height: 600px;` to the div, and then gave the img `width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover;`

Then inside my existing 1024px media query, I gave the div `height: 100%;` to remove its 600px restriction and it works beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the new `srcset` and `sizes` html attributes to achieve that by just passing the cropped image src for each resolution you want:

```
<img srcset="yourimage-320h.jpg 320h,
             yourimage-480w.jpg 480w,
             yourimage-800w.jpg 800w"
     sizes="(max-width: 320px) 280px,
            (min-width: 480px) 440px,
            800px"
     src="yourdefaultimage-800w.jpg">
```

You can set any unit you want `w` and `h` means the real image `width` and the real image `height`.

Useful links:

- https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-css/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using the CSS clip, combine this with a media query and the solution could be css only.

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 1500px) {
.myimg{
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(0px,1500,600px,0px);
}
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 1960px) {
    .myimg{
        position: absolute;
        clip: rect(0px,1960,600px,0px);
    }
    }
```

Alternatively you could use javascript to get more specific and set the

```
$(".myimg").css("clip",'rect(0px,1960,600px,0px)');
```

based on screen detection of width?